# How to merge files in git when directory is already moved to different directory

Tags: git, merge

I was working on a branch taken from master branch for sometime. Now I need to merge my changes. The changes are in specific folder e.g. admin which is a subdirectory in my project.

When I took the latest from master branch, this directory is moved to another location e.g. master/admin. So, now when I try to merge, it shows me all of the admin related files as new file.

I would like to avoid any manual effort to merge and would like a way so that I can let git know that this is not new folder but is the existing folder which has been moved.

Comment: Did you commit your changes before merging the updated branch?

Comment: yes... all of my changes are committed.

Comment: With Git 2.18 (Q2 2018, 2 years later), such a merge (involving a folder rename) should be much easier to do. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.comhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/50537789/6309)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, now when I try to merge, it shows me all of the admin related files as new file.

[***`Restore the old branch`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716) and move the file with `git mv` and not a simple `mv` command.

---

### ***`Why do i have to use git mv and not just mv?`***

Git does not track file names. it store the content inside a `.pack` file and the file names (metadata) inside a `.idx` file and its not part of the content itself.

To get to know it much better read this out how does git store file names
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Tree-Objects

Git cannot track moved files unless you moved them with the `git mv`.
If you simply move or rename them git will track them as new files and will delete the old one.

---

### ***`How to track changes of the moved files?`***

```
# you have to use the --follow flag
git log --follow ./path/to/file
```

Comment: Coo, glad to help.

Comment: But what if new files are added into `olddir` git does only detect the moved files, it does not detect that new added files should be moved too, when you merge an old branch.

Answer (score 2):

Git 2.18 (Q2 2018) should facilitate such a merge.

Rename detection logic in "`diff`" family that is used in "`merge`" has
learned to guess that:

- **when all of `x/a`, `x/b` and `x/c` have moved to `z/a`,
  `z/b` and `z/c`**,
- => it is likely that `x/d` added in the meantime would also
  want to move to `z/d`
  by **taking the hint that the entire directory
  '`x`' moved to '`z`'**.

See [commit 1de70db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1de70dbd1ada0069d1b6cd6345323906cc9a9ed3), [commit 05cf21e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05cf21eba29d18eb6cdece25613c6b1b036872d0), [commit 277292d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/277292d5ae27993d36f35fdd8d561c369b1e0962), [commit a35edc8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a35edc84bdd6134d7aaa7bb0d220941154fe9e7e), [commit c04ba51](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c04ba51739a7771583e31966adb7c472980f3fc3), [commit 2f682e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f682e21a6dc3b7403fd0162252183fdef019274), [commit bd42380](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd42380ef1ec773d1557b28ba6924f4020333143), [commit fd53b7f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd53b7ffd1bd499d24fa48b43a79703355bde512), [commit 6e7e027](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e7e027fe5f4a8d61597a86e7f2b6087e23a759c), [commit bc71c4e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc71c4eebe7ecbb00e06c6b62bc9f0e42aee9d9b), [commit 18797a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18797a3b10e4077473740b953651b0032828d0fb), [commit 64b1abe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64b1abe962b44e6bad84b980e8ea2811302e71c7), [commit 79c4759](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79c47598f5c8c0008ae9281f20c2a041d4cabd93), [commit 9c0743f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c0743fe1e45b3a0ffe166ac949a27f95a3e5c34), [commit 5b047ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b047ac07084b7b8508ea706a9950fc19709358c), [commit f6f7755](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6f775591881036a3c4bfcf6737c9119c251537d), [commit e95ab70](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e95ab70aac4f38f1d365cdc03a7a041920c9c27b), [commit 96e7ffb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96e7ffbdc31d9e02e2548df5d9a9701e5a83651d), [commit 7fe40b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fe40b88efc721bfcbe69f00f950eb9f7a9cd236), [commit ffc16c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffc16c490ad533bc07e6d8ec0226b426166e8442) (19 Apr 2018) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c67de74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c67de747f44c149747f1f4ce5f6d5d6659ba0fbc), 23 May 2018)</sup>

You can see the new tests for merge with moved folders in [`t/t6043-merge-rename-directories.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c67de747f44c149747f1f4ce5f6d5d6659ba0fbc/t/t6043-merge-rename-directories.sh).

It details scenarios like:

```
###########################################################################
# SECTION 1: Basic cases we should be able to handle
###########################################################################

# Testcase 1a, Basic directory rename.
#   Commit O: z/{b,c}
#   Commit A: y/{b,c}
#   Commit B: z/{b,c,d,e/f}
#   Expected: y/{b,c,d,e/f}
```

The expected result would be when merging branch `B` into `A`.

That includes more complex use-cases:

```
# Testcase 1f, Split a directory into two other directories
# 
#   Commit O: z/{b,c,d,e,f}
#   Commit A: z/{b,c,d,e,f,g}
#   Commit B: y/{b,c}, x/{d,e,f}
#   Expected: y/{b,c}, x/{d,e,f,g}
```

The bottom line is:

> So, now when I try to merge, it shows me all of the admin related files as new file

That should no longer be the case with Git 2.18.

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), **when all files from some subdirectory were renamed to the root directory**, the directory rename heuristics would fail to detect that as a rename/merge of the subdirectory to the root directory, which has been corrected.

See [commit da1e295](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da1e295e008ba016eef008385afb2c20c7fc3ff8), [commit 49b8133](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49b8133a9ece199a17db8bb2545202c6eac67485), [commit d3eebaa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3eebaad5ef02284c86d6c4b80199eac58c6729b) (22 Oct 2019) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d980035](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9800351d3386db0c306fde03976d8475d7409a6), 10 Nov 2019)</sup>

> ### [`merge-recursive`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49b8133a9ece199a17db8bb2545202c6eac67485): fix merging a subdirectory into the root directory
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
>
> We allow renaming all entries in e.g. a directory named `z/` into a directory named `y/` to be detected as a `z/ -> y/` rename, so that if the other side of history adds any files to the directory `z/` in the mean time, we can provide the hint that they should be moved to `y/`.
>
> There is no reason to not allow '`y/`' to be the root directory, but the code did not handle that case correctly.

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), that merge fix includes some code cleanup.

See [commit 675ef6b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/675ef6bab807fd94773870db8a1e70447b60a61b), [commit 01ed17d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01ed17dc8c1df52b0545a7eae368a72b79e2a24c), [commit f670adb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f670adb49bd6762ec497fe612e29a51dbe3fcbed) (18 Dec 2019), and [commit 8c02fe6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c02fe60604f402616e864ab68a0a46ccc1b5d10), [commit cb05d6a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb05d6a5ed1ecc687cfb388935381d0b8251f720) (11 Dec 2019) by [René Scharfe (``)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8be0a42](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8be0a428d65e48f42e4600ab0fc91109777d85e1), 25 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`t3501`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f670adb49bd6762ec497fe612e29a51dbe3fcbed): don't create unused file
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>
>
> The file "`out`" became unused with [fd53b7ffd1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd53b7ffd1bd499d24fa48b43a79703355bde512) ("`merge-recursive`: improve `add_cacheinfo` error handling", 2018-04-19, Git v2.18.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c67de747f44c149747f1f4ce5f6d5d6659ba0fbc) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e144d126d74f5d2702870ca9423743102eec6fcd)); get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [`@CodeWizard`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755598) looks good, but if that doesn't work then would there be anything wrong with simply adding the entire new folder?

**Use this:**

```
$ cd master
$ git add admin
```

Comment: Of course that the files have to be added and commited :-)

Comment: adding the files again is not the same. because git will not know that `olddir/file-a` and `newdir/file-a` should have the same history. That means git will not merge these files together.